# How to add list to JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to update a list in with the Swing Component, JComboBox.  How do I add an entire list w/o re-allocating memory to a new JComboBox or w/o iterating through a list and adding an item line by line?

Comment: You will need to create your own `ComboBoxModel` ... the [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one:

```
List list = new ArrayList();

JComboBox box = new JComboBox(list.toArray());
```

The following links could be helpful:

[How to update JComboBox content from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747020/how-to-update-jcombobox-content-from-arraylist)

[How do I populate a JComboBox with an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291704/how-do-i-populate-a-jcombobox-with-an-arraylist)